# Arrange permissions for files in the root

Tags: 18.04

I did shit and I ran: sudo chdmod 777 -R /

Is there a way to fix this?
Without having to reinstall ubuntu everything?

Comment: If you actually run `chdmod` then you were lucky because that's not a proper command. If you instead run `chmod` (without the `d` in the middle), then you might be out of luck.

Comment: New lover of Ubuntu please don't force your new love to change her life style aka permissions it might not go well with the marriage. Please don't mess with root permissions less your ready for trouble.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen LOL. But in real life a bunch of flowers and an apology often can work as a CTRL-Z (aka _undo_). Filesystems aren't that forgiving ;-)